# Push notification in my flutter app and node.js backend

Tags: node.js, firebase, flutter, push-notification

I develop a flutter app and I get data from APIs developed by Node.js and MongoDB in my mobile apps,
Now I want to create a push notification service in my app... How can I do this? What do you think?
Can I use firebase service?

Answer (score 2):

Best way would be to use the "Flutter Local Notifications" Plugin and Firebase Cloud Messaging. (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) (https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

you have a custom backend for the notifications so you can use these as a service and to display notifications.